# Why do we operate with graphical models in VAE, if there are no probabilites involved?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

In the variational autoencoder, I often see graphical models e.g. $P(X|Z)$ for the decoder, but when I looked at code, I don't see any random variables, I see just deterministic network, with composite functions.

I am very confused by that, can someone explain where the magic happens? I am not interested in KL divergence and other stuff. I just don't understand how graphical model > $P(X|Z)$ == composite functions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which type of code you were looking at but e.g. [here](https://keras.io/examples/variational_autoencoder/) they do sampling of random variables. The encoder deterministically maps the input X to mean and standard deviation vectors. Using these vectors you sample Z from factorizing Gaussians with these means and standard deviations. The samples of Z are the again mapped deterministically back to X by the decoder. The [reparametrization trick](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199605/how-does-the-reparameterization-trick-for-vaes-work-and-why-is-it-important) is used to propagate the gradients through the network while only having to sample from standard Gaussians.